# How will I call a method using reflection in Java where the method has 2 parameters?

Tags: reflection, log4j, method-invocation

I am trying to call a method of the Level class in Apache log4j using reflection, which has 2 parameter values. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using an example with the [Level](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Level.html#isInRange-org.apache.logging.log4j.Level-org.apache.logging.log4j.Level-) class fron Log4j2 .

The following calls the method `isInRange(Level, Level)` to determine if a log level is in between a set of two other log levels.

```java
Level warn = Level.WARN;
boolean range = warn.isInRange(Level.ERROR, LEVEL.INFO);
```

can be done using Reflection with:

```java
Level warn = Level.WARN;
Method method = warn.getClass().getMethod("isInRange", Level.class, Level.class);
boolean range = method.invoke(warn, Level.ERROR, Level.INFO);
```

In this case both arguments are `Level` objects, so the class reference `Level.class` is used twice in `getMethod` (as the types of the two arguments).

Then the method is invoked with `method.invoke(warn, Level.ERROR, Level.INFO)`.

The first argument is the instance we want to invoke the method on (in this case `warn`).
If the method we are invoking is static `null` can be used.

The second two arguments are the arguments of the actual function `isInRange`.